# Execute nodejs synchronously

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, synchronous

I am trying to write a function that accepts the mongodb collection name as the paramater and return an instance of the collection so that it can be used to perform CRUD operartions. But when I am trying to return the instance of the collection it returns **'undefined'** as the return statement is executed before the **MongoClient.connect** function finishes its execution.

```
module.exports.dbConnection = function(collectionName)
{
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test";
  var collName;
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) 
  {
      var collName = db.collection(collectionName); 
      console.log(collName)
  });
  return collName;
}
```

Can I get assitance on how I can go about solving this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using at least version 7.10 of Node you can accomplish this using async functions and promises.

```
// You can return a promise and resolve the promise once connected
module.exports.dbConnection = function dbConnection(collectionName) {
  const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test";

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(db.collection(collectionName)); 
    });
  });
}

// You can then call the function within an async function (Node v7.10 and above)
async function fnThatCallsDbConnection() {
  try {
      const collName = await dbConnection('someCollection');
  } catch(e){
    // do something with error
  }
}
```

Something additional you can do is cache your database connection so you don't need to connect every time - here's a way you could do it:

```
let cachedDB;
module.exports.dbConnection = function dbConnection(collectionName) {
  const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test";

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (cachedDB) {
      resolve(cachedDB.collection(collectionName));
    } else {
      MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        cachedDB = db;
        resolve(db.collection(collectionName)); 
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Since I am fairly new to nodejs can you let me know the difference between **var** and **let** while declaring a variable. Becasue I see you have used let cachedDB; can we use var cachedDB too?

Comment: let defines a block scope local variable - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let. Yes you can use var here.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to accomplish this is to use a callback. Accept a callback argument, and then pass your desired information to that function when the operation is complete.

```
module.exports.dbConnection = function(collectionName, cb)
{
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/test";
  var collName;
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) 
  {
      var collName = db.collection(collectionName); 
      cb(collName); // invoke our callback
  });
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
dbConnection('collName', function (coll) {
    console.log(coll);
    // do something else with our collection
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a follow up question, How ideal is it to open the connection each time an api call is made? does it create a overhead on the database? How can i solve this?